# mpdf library does not display polish characters

Tags: php, unicode, mpdf

I use "Great Vibes" font when generating PDF files, unfortunately it does not display Polish characters. However, when creating graphics in Photoshop, using the same font, all Polish characters are displayed correctly. In mpdf library configuration I have:

`"mode" => "utf-8"`

In the generated pdf I get a word with a break: "Miko aj"
But if I copy all this text and paste it e.g. into notepad it turns out that Polish sign is "hidden" and when i copy and paste this string I get correctly word: "Mikołaj".

My mpdf settings:

```
$mpdf  =   new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
'tempDir'       =>  UPLOADS . '/project_files/temp/',
'margin_left'   =>  0, 
'margin_right'  =>  0,
'margin_top'    =>  0,
'margin_bottom' =>  0,
'margin_header' =>  0,
'margin_footer' =>  0,  
'mode'          =>  'utf-8',
'fontDir'       =>  $newFontsDirs,
'fontdata'      =>  $fontData + $projectFont 
]);
```

I do not use HTML code when generating pdf. I use the $mpdf->WriteText() method.

I've changed modes and looked up similar problems on the web. I looked for a solution in the mpdf documentation.

Comment: How did you obtain the Great Vibes font? Where is the rest of the code, especially showing the call `$mpdf->WriteText()` that is causing you issue?

Comment: I added my own font directory and added my own font list. 

`$mpdf->WriteText(0, ( $size['height'] *( $row[ "pos_h" ] / 100 ) ), $txt_to_write );`

The generated pdf looks good, just missing those few specific characters.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specific details. More beneficial would be the entire script and the variable values you are using that is causing you problems and how they are obtained. eg: `$txt_to_write = '....';` coming from form or database. Unicode can be very fickle to implement based on a number of factors, such as different environments/platforms. (Local vs Uploaded vs Designated) such as publishing from Windows to Linux and PHP vs HTML vs Database storage, etc. The more info we have the better.

Comment: @WillB. this will be difficult because it's Wordpress and Wocommerce mechanisms. I can't point out here the whole process of collecting the data, storing it in the database, reading from the database and generating a PDF document from it.

Comment: Understood, simply the script example of where the problem actually occurs `$mpdf->WriteText()` and the data being passed to it is needed however. EG: output from `var_dump($txt_to_write)` or similar data point reference. Right now we have "debug my code" with no ability to actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: From that point, it would be up to you to ensure the character sets are uniform throughout, instead of a mix of something like latin1 (ISO-8859-1), so that the data is not being lost somewhere. PHP is set to UTF-8, php script files are saved as UTF-8, database table collation is utf8 or MySQL utf8mb4 and the HTML charset is set to UTF-8. And the selected font supports the characters supplied to it as UTF-8.